# NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains trouble (losing hair fast)

Tags: iphone, uikit, filesystems

I am getting bald quite quick and need help!

I am writing an app which needs to access directories. I was hoping to get a path of the form
**/Users/me/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/6958D21C-C94B-4843-9EF1-70406D0CA3A3/Documents**.

However my app is giving me **/Users/me/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Documents** which is not what I want because have no write access.

Here is a thoroughly stripped down edition of my code. Note that you need to look at the console in the simulator to see the output. I have checked all the references I know and have no success to change the behaviour. Is it some compiler option? Or something I have to change in Info.plist? Anybody please...

Update: For some very strange reason my app is not being sandboxed. Why?

File DirTestAppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DirTestAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> 
{
    UIWindow *window;
}

@end
```

File DirTestAppDelegate.m

```
#import "DirTestAppDelegate.h"

@implementation DirTestAppDelegate
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(documentsDirectory);
}


- (void)dealloc 
{
        [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was an issue of the provisioning not set properly. Took hours to fix :-(

Comment: Can you post the solution and let me know what you did?  I'm having a similar problem getting the directory in the distribution configuration.  Thanks - Joe

Comment: I would also love to hear your solution, I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Please - what was the answer.  I'm having the same problem and can't find anything about it.

Comment: John, may I ask you for the solution of the described problem?

Comment: Bump! Please let us know. I seem to have set the provisioning properly, too, but no dice.

Comment: For all who are still looking for an answer, follow this question where I asked the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515979/nssearchpathfordirectoriesindomains-returns-the-wrong-directory/6577367