# Document Directory on iPhone is invalid

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, path

I attempt to get the path of the document directory on the iPhone SDK with the following code:

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

I'm in distribution and not debug configuration.  In debug a valid path is returned. Also I'm using iPhone OS 3.0

Please help!

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give you any specific advice, but [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175367/nssearchpathfordirectoriesindomains-trouble-losing-hair-fast) implies that it's happened to someone else, and that the issue was to do with provisioning. Your best bet would be to comment on the answer to that question and see if you can get a response, since it looks like he found a solution.