# NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains returns the wrong directory

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdocumentdirectory

I'm using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)` to get the application documents directory in my app, but the array that's returned contains only one object, and it's an unwritable, incorrect directory:

/Users/me/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/Documents

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175367/nssearchpathfordirectoriesindomains-trouble-losing-hair-fast) which indicates that the problem is related to provisioning, but the answer says little more than that. So I guess I'm asking a duplicate question, but the answer to that question is insufficient, so I'm hoping to get an actual answer in this one.

Comment: The answer to that question is indeed awfully unsatisfactory. When you do find the solution here, please flag for a mod to merge/close the other.

Comment: Does the console show any errors at all?

Comment: What some of the other answers/comments seem to be indicating is that this function might actually be returning an array with *more than one* directory. Can you check and see if it is?

Comment: @jtbandes Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the question with clarification - I'm only getting one directory.

Comment: @OscarMk I do see an error in the console, but it's due to the fact that I'm trying to write a .sqlite file to the directory indicated in the question, which is unwritable.

Comment: @Josh Brown could you post that error please.

Comment: @OscarMk That error is a direct result of the problem described in the question. Seems like unnecessary information, no?

Comment: Hmm ... so one reason that the directory returned might be different that what you'd expect for an app could be related to the Xcode target type. This wouldn't happen to be a testing target would it? in which case the correct answer could well be an answer w/o an application GUID in it, since in fact it's not an application. This google group discussion implies that if this is the case, you'd be good with simply creating the directory: http://groups.google.com/group/google-toolbox-for-mac/browse_thread/thread/887ee7a4d5cdc885/a4b6d87e0ecfc73c

Comment: Just for grins, I created the directory /Users/me/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/Documents from the terminal window, and now it appears to run. There are still test errors, but those might be real.

Comment: Rob - you're right. The issue must have been that this was in a testing target.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hmm ... so one reason that the directory returned might be different that what you'd expect for an app could be related to the Xcode target type. This wouldn't happen to be a testing target would it? in which case the correct answer could well be an answer w/o an application GUID in it, since in fact it's not an application. This [google group discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/google-toolbox-for-mac/browse_thread/) implies that if this is the case, you'd be good with simply creating the directory.

Just for grins, I created the directory /Users/me/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/Documents from the terminal window, and now it appears to run. There are still test errors, but those might be real.

I'd recommend that you change your test app to create the documents directory if it's missing - something like:

```
  if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL])
        NSLog(@"Error: Create folder failed %@", NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES));
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                        inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, URLsForDirectory:inDomains: is available only in iOS 4.0 and above, and I'm supporting 3.1.3. Is there another way to find this directory that's available pre-4.0?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but why are you still supporting 3.x? No point in losing productivity for < 5% of users.

Comment: I tried this approach but had the same issue. It's giving me exactly the same directory as NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
 /**
 Returns the path to the application's Documents directory.
 */
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
```

I believe you are only missing the lastObject message.

Comment: Thanks. This is, in fact, what I'm doing - the NSString that's returned from lastObject is the incorrect path specified in the question.

Comment: @Josh Brown Does the message return more than 1 item in the array?, have you tried writing to any of the returning paths?

Comment: @Josh Brown the problem could also be with the msg stringByAppendingPathComponent: if you are not passing it a valid file name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same issue, and in my case it's because I'm running the code from an XCTest class.

My guess is that the tests are not run in the application sandbox.

That's because my tests are related to a static library project, included in the main project.

As soon as I run the exact same code from a run of my app, the paths are returned correctly.

Hope this helps.